# Spring REST shows a 404 error on POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am getting error on REST POST requests

project hierarchy:

[image: project hierarchy]

I am using H2 db and this is how I configured it:

```
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db/daDb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/student",consumes = "application/json")
public class StudentController
{
    private final studentDAO studentDAO;
    @Autowired
    public StudentController()
    {
        this.studentDAO = new studentDAO();
    }   

    @PostMapping(path = "/")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void postRequest(@NonNull @RequestBody student student)
    {
        student.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        this.studentDAO.add(student);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class studentDAO extends daoTemplate<student,studentRepo>
{
    @Autowired
    private studentRepo studentRepo;

    @Override
    public void add(student temp)
    {
        this.studentRepo.save(temp);
    }

    @Override
    public void patchUpdate(student student,UUID id)
    {
        Optional<student> target = super.getRepo().findById(id);
        if(target.isPresent())
        {
            if(Objects.nonNull(student.getName()))
                target.get().setName(student.getName());
            if(Objects.nonNull(student.getSubjects()))
                target.get().setSubjects(student.getSubjects());
        }
    }

}
```

The DAO Template

```
@Service
public abstract class daoTemplate<entity,repo extends CrudRepository<entity,UUID>>
{
    private repo repo;

    public repo getRepo()
    {
        return repo;
    }

    public entity get(UUID id)
    {
        Optional<entity> temp = this.repo.findById(id);
        if(temp.isPresent())
        {
            return temp.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Iterable<entity> getAll()
    {
        return this.repo.findAll();
    }

    public void update(entity temp)
    {
        if (Objects.nonNull(temp))
            this.repo.save(temp);
    }

    public void patchUpdate(entity temp,UUID id)
    {
        //Manually Written
    }

    public void delete(UUID id)
    {
        if(this.repo.existsById(id))
            this.repo.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void add(entity temp)
    {
        this.repo.save(temp);
    }

    public boolean check(UUID id)
    {
        return this.repo.existsById(id);
    }
}
```

Student Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class student
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    private int age;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students",cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Collection<subject>subjects;

    public void addSubjectByID(Collection<UUID> subjectsIDs)
    {
        if(!subjectsIDs.isEmpty())
        {
            subjectDAO dao = new subjectDAO();
            subjectsIDs.stream().distinct()
                    .map((id) -> {
                        return dao.get(id);
                    })
                    .forEach((subject) -> {
                        this.subjects.add(subject);
                    });
        }
    }

}
```

The URL : http://localhost:8080/student

The JSON request:

```
    {
    "name": "khalid kbashi",
    "age": 16,
    "subject": null
}
```

Response:

[image]

---

UPDATES ON CODE :
1- added `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`  to application.proprites
2- added and handled some exceptions

Comment: you should show your complete request.

Comment: Please don't add things like "solved" to a question title. Either accept the answer that helped you solve the problem, or post your own answer and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by:

1. Deleting the constructor from the controller
2. adding field injection the studentDAO in the controller
3. removing @Service from daoTemplate
4. adding an extra dash to the URI from "http://localhost:8080/student" to "http://localhost:8080/student/"

I think number 4 was the main issue.

Comment: Please be aware that using field injection is usually recommended against. Using constructor injection is almost always the better choice.

Answer (score -2):

On your post method you are passing two students objects:

```
public void postRequest(@NonNull @RequestBody student student)
```

It should be:

```
public void postRequest(@NonNull @RequestBody Student student)
```

Also I would recommend you to don't add anything to the path on your post method, so instead of:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/")
```

Use just:

```
@PostMapping
```

Comment: hi nalbert i already done it and the problem is still somewhere , you can check the controller class again for better understanding . thank you for you time

Comment: "On your post method you are passing two students objects:" um, no, that's not how Java works. The class is called `student` (with a lower-case `s`). While a violation of the established naming conventions, `student student` does NOT mean two `student` objects are passed in. It's identical to `Student student`, but actually compiles because `student` is the class name; `Student` is not. It's ugly, but it's valid Java